# Difference in meaning and grammar structure

Tags: grammar

I want to send a letter to some one to inform him that I received the Items in good condition.

There any difference between the two sentences?

A: I want to inform you that the Items were received in good condition.

B: I want to inform you that the Items have been received in good condition.

Comment: Difference in verb tense, but no difference in meaning. Do you notice that the words "I want to inform you that" are entirely unnecessary?

Comment: There is a potentially slight difference in meaning in that with the present perfect tense the situation is conceived of as having some kind of current relevance, relevance to the present: perhaps the items have only just been received. By contrast, A does not express any such relationship.